# How to return the total matches on a Cosmos db query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have setup an api that will query our Cosmos db and return the JSON results back to the front end app.  There is a user defined limit on the number of results.  If the number of results exceed the limit then I pass back the token to the front end and they can call for the next group of rows.  The issue is I would like to provide a count of the Total Number of Matches back to the application.  I have looked at the query statistics but don't see where there is a total count.

On the call to CreateDocumentQuery, i'm setting MaxItemCount to the limit, and RequestContinuation either null or the continuationToken.  Looking at QueryMetrics I found RetrievedDocumentCount, but that does not seem to have the correct value.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

x-ms-max-item-count request header controls how many documents should be returned to user.
Default value is 100
if your query returns 150 documents, your request will return first 100 documents and it will return a continuation token in response header(x-ms-continuation). If there is a token, you need to send another request with the given token to get the rest of the data.
SDK should be doing that for you automatically. Can you share some of your code. I might have a better answer then.
You can check out my post about this too.
https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/04/introduction-to-continuation-tokens-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So what I'm trying to accomplish is to return the first x number of rows but still communicate the total result set back, without retrieving all results.  Yes, I'm using the continuation token, but that is being passed to the client so they can decide if they want the next batch.  However, the total number of results needs to be communicated back to the client in the first response.

Comment: `query=client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
QuerySpec, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = pageSize, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, PopulateQueryMetrics = true, RequestContinuation = continuationToken }).AsDocumentQuery();
FeedResponse<T> feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
List<T> results = new List<T>();
foreach (dynamic r in feedResponse)
{results.Add(r);}
long totalDocs = feedResponse.QueryMetrics.Values.First().RetrievedDocumentCount;
return (results,feedResponse.ResponseContinuation, totalDocs);
}`